# String output as an input dataset variable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, features, parameters, string

I have a model which creates topology with rules and validate itself.
But I got used to working with layers in TOC and have a script in Calculate value tool that with a help of Parse path tool make a string output with feature dataset path in.
Here is a script:

```py
def GetPath(lyr):
    import os
    mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    target=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,lyr)[0]
    return target.dataSource
```

And here is a part of model I want to be working.
[image]

Unfortunately, Create topology tool requires path not to some output value or variable, but probably direct file path. That is a reason for crashing of model due to the non-existance of dataset parameter.

Anyway is it possible to make an Input Feature dataset as a variable which records a path from string data? In my case it should be like %FDS%.

Comment: When you complete the Calculate Value tool what do you set the output type to?

Comment: @Hornbydd Variant. I tried Feature Dataset, but it makes model crashing, because it still finds a path to layer, not dataset.

Comment: Defining the calculate variable as Feature Dataset and removing parse path, did you try output_value for the topology in dataset?

Comment: @artwork21 I tried but it calculates a path to layer, not dataset.

Comment: Is your GetPath(lyr) call lyr variable a string of the layer name in ArcMap?

Comment: @artwork21 I'm not sure about an answer, I just found that code somehow. GetPath has a reference to a "tline" layer which is in TOC. Calculate value tool makes a Feature Dataset file path including tline layer. Smth like C:\folder\file.gdb\fd\tline ("fd" is dataset). And I need to have just C:\folder\file.gdb\fd

Comment: Does the fd have to be referenced from a map or could it be defined by the user before running the model?  Reason I ask is because you make the in dataset for the topology tool a model parameter and each time the model is run the end user could browse and define this layer.  You could also just hard code the in dataset for the topology tool if it will not change over time.

Comment: In my case, dataset is referenced from a map and it can be named with another word. I want my model to be run without any parameters, it just have to scan the TOC for layer called "tline" , find a path to the dataset and create topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set Calculate Value output to be FeatureDataset
2. Remove Parse path tool
3. Replace you code with the following:

```py
def GetPath(lyr):
    import arcpy,string
    mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    featureLayer=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,lyr)[0]

    # Get FULL path
    path = featureLayer.dataSource

    # Get FeatureClass name
    fc = featureLayer.datasetName

    # Get index position of featureclass name in full path, -1 strips off \
    idx = string.rfind(path,fc) - 1

    # Return FeatureDataset
    return path[:idx]
```

4. Connect tool to create Topology tool

Comment: everything is ok when I launch this model from model builder window. But when I launch it from the Catalog it crashes. The reason is a feature class, a path to which I calculate also through Calculate Value tool that has Feature class output. Topology is created right in Dataset I need but "Add feature class to topology" doesn't react on Calculate Value tool or something like `%Feature dataset%\tline`; it wants to add "tline" taken from the last launch of model within ModelBuilder interface.